# iphone - changing the width of a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am trying to change the width of a UITableViewCell.

I have tried everything. Now I am trying to change it on

-

```
 (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // trying everything... 
    CGRect bounds = cell.contentView.bounds;
    bounds.size.width = bounds.size.width * 0.8f;
    cell.contentView.bounds = bounds;
    cell.backgroundView.bounds = bounds;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView.bounds = bounds;
    cell.bounds = bounds;

}
```

No change at all. Any thoughts? thanks

NOTE: I need the table width to be unchanged, because this table has a background image that must remain filling all width.

Comment: try to set its frame, rather than the bounds

Comment: no change at all. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make your own CustomCell class

that you can customize on your purpose about frame size , content inside or other things about UIView component such a UILabel , UIImage , etc..

and then take your CustomCell class for UITableview Cell method `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

hope it helps you

Comment: I tried that, but still, there's no way to set the width of a cell. The only way was using - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
, but apple has deprecated that and the other methods will fall in the same problem I am having right now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: just to complement. I am doing that programmatically, cause I never use interface builder. I hate it.

Comment: @DigitalRobot May I ask question.. Example: you wanna make cell width 150px and your UItableview width 320px,right? so, you should make your custom UIView inside customCell Layout. It look seem you have your cell width 150px,right? and use another technique to hide any unnecessary layout outside your specific UIView inside. sorry for my english if it made you hard to understand.

Comment: @DigitalRobot yep, there're many various technique for our purpose. In my experience,Combining your manaully code and the Interface Builder positioning is pretty good work for me.Try to understand and do you code well. Keep fighting!

Comment: Hi, I understand Interface Builder, but I don't like it. It is faster to do in code. I may end using what you've said: creating a smaller UIImageView and put that inside. Anyway, Apple should make it easier.

Comment: @DigitalRobot I think so. Hope it gonna be faster in next version. :)

Answer (score 1):

May be `cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;` will help you?

Comment: nope. The cell continues arrogantly to defy any try to change its size... :/

Comment: Also you have one more variant: add subview on cell and catch all touch events and call -tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: